# Tcpdump command shows 10 requests per second on SSH

Tags: vps

When I type "tcpdump" on any VPS server I own I get many requests apparently from my own machine to the SSH port. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Tcpdump will output to the terminal. Terminal is created by ssh and anything on it is transferred over ssh between your vps and your client machine. This is basically what you see in tcpdump.

So yes, this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual `tcpdump` commandline and filter options:

You're probably accessing your VPS over SSH to run `tcpdump`...

Each bit of output from the tcpdump command itself will need to be transmitted over SSH to your screen and gets registered by tcpdump (again generating more SSH traffic)

So that is completely expected.